# how to add image Placeholder if image not found on frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, placeholder

how i can add image place holder on front-end page when image is not uploaded or not found in both cases.

actually, i am working on custom module, in which i have to fill the form front-end in which i have the option of image uploading a photo. i want that if someone does not upload the image, then there is a default image in it.[image]

Comment: Have you got solution? I want to do same as your requirement.

Comment: yes i have the solution for this.

Comment: Can you please share that solution or piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but simply login to the backend.

Select: Stores, Configuration, Catalog, then scroll down to Product Image PlaceHolders (see image below)

[image: Product Image PlaceHolders]

Then simply upload the various custom placeholder images from your computer.

Comment: i am working on custom module. So these configuration won't work.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more details as to what the situation is so that someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: actually i have to fill the form front-end in which i have the option of image uploading a photo. i want that if someone does not upload the image, then there is a default image in it.